# Apple alu keyboard on Precise

Tags: keyboard, apple

my Apple keyboard (ISO) doesn't work correctly in Ubuntu 12.04 but worked flawless in Lucid.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is "alu" short for aluminum? Did you upgrade to 12.04 from 10.04 or do an erase and install? (I'm just trying to determine if some configuration that was performed on Lucid might have been erased when you moved to 12.04?)

Comment: Good question! When I tried to use Apple keyboard with Ubuntu I found that the function keys do not work - do you experience the same? Or what exactly does not work for you?

Comment: it's a fresh install. F10 always opens the menu (annoying in mc) and I cannot type "<" and ">".

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard) is what I use to switch the settings on my keyboard. Most of the configuration only states that it works up to Ubuntu 11.04, but I change the function-mode successfully on 12.04.

Comment: Its working in most applications but intellij Idea (java IDE). Does anybody knows why and how to solve it?

Comment: i reinstalled it, installed open-jdk at first and then folowed http://www.devsniper.com/ubuntu-12-04-install-sun-jdk-6-7/ - and ~/.Xmodmap now works ok in intellij idea too.

Comment: @palmic, did you reinstall open-jdk, and then reinstall Intellij Idea? (faced the same issue)

Comment: Actually, my issue was different, that was it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1748058

Comment: @yetanothercoderu this is old topic, i installed oracle JDK in synaptic (found repo) and did not faced any problem with that. Definitely recomends..